# Why does my annotated promoworks for some accounts and not others? What % is affected by the difference?

Tags: email, gmail, schema, google-schemas, gmail-promo-tab

My annotated email promo is only showing the extra markup in some gmail accounts and so I can't test how it's displaying.

Does anyone know what proportion of gmail accounts display annotated promo's and why those that don't display them are affected as such.

My settings for the gmail app include bundles, conversations and images are all on and i've the latest version of gmail and still do not display as expected.

I don't see promos from any other companies either so i can't check against that, But at least their company images are displaying - where ours is not.

Comment: Does this have something to do with programming?  If so, can you clarify via an [edit] to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I've been given a figure of 25% of gmail accounts are seeing the promotion at the offices of our ESP.

Further- I am now seeing the promo as intended in my gmail app.

I speculate that perhaps my opening the promo several times- in a sense- 'engaging' with the brand, has resulted in now seeing the promotion and the marked up content.

I also note that a new user that we proof to, is receiving the promo in the 'top promo's section -but not with the added graphics - but then he's a new user and perhaps needs to engage with the content further.

Answer (score 0):

Most Gmail accounts, with a few exceptions, should be seeing promotions. For a while, Google was withholding groups of users for testing.

Whether or not users are seeing *your* promotions is another matter and seems dependent on what other promotional email is currently in the user's inbox and how much a user has interacted with your brand.

As of January 2020, G Suite users do not see promotions, nor do users using the desktop web client. Desktop support has been reportedly *"coming soon"* for several months already.